# restrict yang leafref key identifier without extra leaf

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang

I have a yang model with a leafref, which is pointing to a list inside of a other list.
Basically something like this:

```
list some-names
{
    key "name";
    leaf name
    {
        type string;
    }

    list some-other-names
    {
        key "name";
        leaf name
        {
            type string;
        }
    }  
}
```

I want to point from outside with a leafref to the `some-other-names` list but only the ones with upper name equals to foo.
Unfortunately the leafref has to have a `current()` for restriction.
So my current solution is the following but requires a extra leaf which
is total unnecessary for configuration .

```
leaf foo
{
    type string;
    deafault "foo";
}
leaf some-leaf-ref
{
    type leafref
    {
        path "/some-names[name = current()/../foo]/some-other-names/name";
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler way than this, which does **not need a additional leaf** for restricting the name of `some-names` to a certain value?

BTW this I already tried but its not a correct path-arg:

```
leaf some-leaf-ref
{
    type leafref
    {
        path "/some-names[name = 'foo']/some-other-names";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something along the lines of:

```
  leaf some-leafref {
    must "/some-names[name = 'foo']/some-other-names/name = .";
    type leafref {
      path "/some-names/some-other-names/name";
    }
  }
```

So, no predicate in the `path` expression, yet with an additional `must` restriction - the two expressions are essentially ANDed together. YANG specification does mention that a path expression may evaluate to a node set that contains more than one node, and it doesn't say predicates are mandatory per key (unlike for `instance-identifiers`). Seems like hackery to me, though, or ugly at least.

Perhaps what you really want is a leafref leaf child to your outer `list` (`some-names`), that has a `when` to make it valid only when `../name = 'foo'`.

```
  list some-names {
    key "name";
    leaf name {
      type string;
    }

    list some-other-names {
      key "name";
      leaf name {
        type my-type;
      }
    }  

    leaf some-leafref {
      when "../name = 'foo'";
      type leafref {
        path "../some-other-names/name";
      }
    }
  }
```